# Show form button if the form is directed through specific button in OPENERP

Tags: python, xml, forms, odoo

I want to know that if its possible to set the visibility of a form's button based on how this form is being called. Like there are two forms 'A' and 'B'. Now the button on form 'A' calls the form 'B'. All I want to show the form 'B' button only if its called through that specific form 'A' button. I dont know how this will be achievable but I think I will have to set the attributes on the button of form B. But how to check if form A button is clicked. Thats where I am stuck. I need some guidance on this.Every help will be appreciated.
 the code to call form 'b':

```
def edits(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    for id in ids:
        deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
        my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)

    return{
          'view_type': 'form',
          'view_mode': 'form',  
          'res_model': 'product.product',
          'res_id':my_id,
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
          'nodestroy':False,
          'target': 'inline',          
          }
```

I want the form 'b' button to be visible only if i open it through 'edits' button.

Answer (score 0):

To open the form 'B' from the form 'A', you need to define a method in your object to call the form 'B'. On this method, you can set a context, so put, for example,

```
def edits(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    for id in ids:
        deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
        my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)

    context['from_edits'] = True

    return{
      'view_type': 'form',
      'view_mode': 'form',  
      'res_model': 'product.product',
      'res_id':my_id,
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
      'nodestroy':False,
      'target': 'inline',       
      'context': context,   
      }
```

and in the XML declaration of your form B, you can try

```
<button string="To form A" type="object" name="to_form_a" invisible="context.get('from_edits')" />
```

Comment: what is meant by 'from_a' , do I give the model of form 'b' here?

Comment: I tried with your solution but I cannot see button when coming from form'A' and can see button when coming from elsewhere. I tried this on form'B' :  <button name="saves" string="SAVE" type="object" invisible="context.get('product_product')" />

Answer (score 0):

Just change small things in button declaration

```
<button name="saves" string="SAVE" type="object" invisible="context.get('product_product',False)" />
```

And make sure you have set proper value in context

```
context['product_product'] = True
```

Hope this helps.